# How can I save unknown data types to the database?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

I'm preparing a data analysis program with pandas. Users transfer data from the excel file to the program. Column names taken from the Excel file are constantly changing. Therefore, I do not know the column names and data types that I will record in the database. How can I save unfamiliar types of data in the database.The database I use is postqresql. Only if I understand the logic I can move forward. very thank you.

Comment: You're basically looking for schema on read. Traditional RDBMSs are schema on write.

Comment: So the order of things is Excel --> Pandas --> Postgres, correct?.  What is being done in the Pandas portion? What is being done in the Postgres portion? Are you going to be transferring using `CSV` and/or using `pandas.to_sql`?

Comment: It can be any file type. I can also get data from a database

Comment: As an example of a tool to go from `CSV` to `SQL` see [csvsql](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvsql.html). It will do type inference.

Comment: actually what I think. How can I determine the types of data when registering with the database?

Comment: Without a flow chart of where data is coming from and where it is going this question is not going to get an answer that is of any use.  In particular the part about inferring data types from the data itself. All that can be said is it can be done to some degree as  `ETL`(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) is based on just this. It comes down to proper planning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relational database are not well suited for storing data do not adhere to a fixed schema.

I see two options:

- Analyze the data you have and create a new table that fits the data before you insert them into the database.

  The question is what to do with all these tables in PostgreSQL.
- Use a table with a `jsonb` column (not only this column of course; you need at least a primary key) and format the data you have as JSON.

  The question is what to do with all these random data.

Comment: I guess I've been too far from the subject. You are right. Postgresql is not a good choice for storing unknown data types. What you are saying is very logical. I guess I'll need to work with databases like mongodb.

Comment: pivot or group_by operations will be done with this data

Comment: actually what I think. How can I determine the types of data when registering with the database?

Comment: You get the data types from the input data, right? I'm not saying that you should *not* choose PostgreSQL. I think that it will probably be "more natural" to store such data in MongoDB, but the essential problem will remain the same: how do you make sense of and extract useful information from totally unstructured data?